# Knockout.js + ES6 + Underscore Templating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get my head around using Knockout.js to create a product cart. Each item outputs a plus and minus button as well as a remove button. My aim is to be able to have the plus and minus increment or decrement the quantity, and the remove button to remove the product. My constraints are that I can't use JQuery.

I've attempted to separate my app concerns so that I have ShopView, ShopModel and ShopItem (ShopItem is the individual item that is pushed to an observable array within the ShopModel). The buttons are rendered, however when clicking on an individual remove/add/minus button and logging the value of this to the console I only am able to see my JS class, not the individual element to remove or alter. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I've included the bare-bones snippets of the key parts:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/html" id="itemsList">
    {{ _.each(items(), function(item) { }}
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: minus" class='left-minus'>&ndash;</a>
        <p class="qty" data-bind="text: item.quantity"></p>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: remove" class="remove-product">Remove</a>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: plus" class='right-plus'>&plus;</a>
     {{ }) }}
</script>

<section data-bind="template: { name: 'itemsList' }" class="items-inner"></section>`
```

**shopView.js**

```
class shopView {
    constructor() {
        this.setupShop()

    }

    setupShop(){
        this.model.items.push(new Item(97, 'cover-3', '/media/img/cover-3.jpg', 'Issue 5', 'Spring Summer 17', 1, 10));
        ko.applyBindings(this.model);
    }
}

module.exports = shopView
```

**shopView.js**

```
let ko = require('knockout');

class shopItem{
    constructor (id, url, thumbnail, title, edition, quantity, price) {
        this.id = ko.observable(id)(),
        this.thumbnail = ko.observable(url)(),
        this.title = ko.observable(title)(),
        this.edition = ko.observable(edition)(),
        this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity)(),
        this.price = ko.observable(price)();
        this.add = function(){

        };
        this.minus = function(){

        };
    }
}

module.exports = shopItem;
```

**shopModel**

**Shop Item**

```
class shopModel {
    constructor() {
        this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

        this.minus = function(item){
            console.log(item);
        };

        this.plus = function(){

        };

        this.remove = (item) => {
            this.items.remove(item);
        };
    }
}


module.exports = shopModel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` binding provides the current `$data` value to the callback function. But because you are using Underscore for the loop, `$data` isn't the item. You can change your `click` binding to something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() {minus(item)}" class='left-minus'>&ndash;</a>
```